# how to create tables of events that the number's are unknown with SQLite

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite, database-design

i ll start to develop an iPhone application but i got a question/problem.

i was thinking about storing all the data in one single and huge table but than while i was drawing a schema, i noticed that i ll store events- trigger events like placed in IBActions, or in viewDidLoad's  i ll keep the count but the real question is, i need to store the dates and timestamps of this events as well.Like one user may trigger "home screen appeared" 100 times, keeping the count is easy but how can i store the dates?Should i create a separate table to keep each events and their timestamps?

If thats the case i don't know how many events there will be, wouldn't it be so much of a garbae tables?

In the end i'll send these SQLite informations to my back-end so it should be neat.

Can this be done in one single table?Am i missing some points?

Comment: Why build your own system for that? Mobile App Analytics by Google (http://www.google.se/analytics/mobile/) is easy to implement, and adds a lot of features.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in one table, you would need a record ( row ) for each event. You could

```
select count(1) from events ....
```

to get the count, order by date_created with a limit N clause to get the most N recent, etc. If you insisted on keeping just one row per event, then no, I can't think of a clean way to keep track of all event dates without a second table.

To answer your other questions though, you can automatically assign the data of a record's entry by defining the column like this ..

```
DATE_CREATED DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

and not including that field on your insert statement. That is really your cleanest solution.